# Have to click dialog twice to dismiss, launching a dialog from listpreference in preferences fragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a ListPreference in my preferences xml.
These are displayed in a preferences fragment, launched from MainActivity.

MainActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        //toggle back arrow on back stack change
                        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                            } else {
                                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                                MainActivity.this.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            }
        });

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            fragment = new FragmentSettings();
        } else if (id == R.id.action_1) {
            fragment = new FragmentAction1();
        }

        //add fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_main, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml (loaded into activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Preferences

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/number_array_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/number_array_values"
            android:key="NUMBERS"
            android:title="Choose number" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

It brings up a ListPreference with some entries/values pulled from two arrays.
I have one option called "Custom", which is set in the listener to bring up a dialog box so the user can input their own value.
You have to click twice to get rid of the dialog box. The first time does nothing and a bit of shadow around the dialog box disappears, and the second click finally gets rid of the dialog.

I have a custom dialog xml (dialog_number_picker):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/dialog_number_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My preference settings fragment, where the dialog is launched from OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener if the user selects the "Custom" option:

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    private Context context;

    private ListPreference myListPreference;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener sharedPreferenceChangeListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        context = getContext();

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        //reset default values only on the first read
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.preferences, false);

        myListPreference = findPreference("NUMBERS");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Settings");

        sharedPreferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                if(key.equals("NUMBERS") && myListPreference.getEntry().equals("Custom")) {

                    setAlertDialog();

                }
            }
        };
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    }

    private void setAlertDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_number_picker, null);

        final NumberPicker numberPicker = subView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_number_picker);

        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("Message");
        builder.setView(subView);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        numberPicker.setMaxValue(50);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
        numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int i1) {

            }
        });

        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code, and it works as expected for me. I'm not sure that I'm following your description correctly, though. What exactly do you mean by having to click twice? Do you mean, for example, that you have to click "Done" twice for your `AlertDialog` to dismiss? Or are you clicking something else the second time; I mean, like a dimmed-out screen leftover from a `Dialog`?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply, yes I have to click twice to dismiss it. Clicking anything. 'Done', 'Cancel' buttons, outside the dialog box, all require two clicks. On the first click I can see a bit of shadow around the dialog box disappearing. 
I assume it's because of the listpreference behind the dialog box.

Comment: OK, that sounds like you've inadvertently loaded multiple `FragmentSettings` instances, one atop another. Indeed, I just quickly modified my test to check that, and now I see that behavior. Please [edit] your question to show us how you're loading `FragmentSettings`, in the code and layout XML.

Comment: Sorry Mike, you're completely right, I forgot to add that! Question edited to include that. There's no layout XML for FragmentSettings, it just inflates the preferences.xml

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase that well. I meant the layout that `FragmentSettings` is loaded into; the one with `content_main` in it.

Comment: Ah, right, updated!

Comment: Well, there looks to be no real issues in the layouts, though having anything inside a `Fragment`-container `ViewGroup` – i.e., your `content_main` `<RelativeLayout>` – is usually not what you want to do. You might not need that `content_main` at all; e.g., if you could do with a simple container `<FrameLayout>` in `activity-main`. Anyhoo, I'm guessing this is happening after you've switched `Frament`s once or twice, or possibly rotated the device after a switch, etc. The root cause appears to be the `add()` transaction you're using. That will just keep stacking `Fragment`s on top of each...

Comment: ...other. You could change that to a `replace()`, which will remove previous `Fragment` instances from `content_main`. Otherwise, you'll need to somehow handle removing or hiding those old instances yourself, rather than adding each time `onOptionsItemSelected()` is called.